# EIP 1559 transaction structure

Tags: contract-deployment, json-rpc, sendrawtransaction

I am trying to develop a web3 library for deploying a contract, interct with the smart contract functions etc using the RPC methods in Golang. I know there is go-ethereum but doing it for my own learning. I got stuck in between as there is less information online regarding this.

For deploying the contract, I need to use eth_sendRawTransaction as there is no inbuilt wallet.
I am following the below steps.

1. Decalre the transaction struct with all the fields
   type transaction struct {
   Type                    uint8
   Nonce                   uint64
   BaseFeePerGas           uint64
   MaxPriorityFeePerGas    uint64
   MaxFeePerGas            uint64
   To                      string
   Value                   *big.Int
   Data                    string
   ChainID                 uint32
   }

Is the datatype and order of the fields correct. The order is important for RLP encoding/decoding right?

2.Serialize the transaction ( RLP encode ) and calculate the keccak256 hash.
For RLP encoding, I have created my own code.
There is no standard package for keccak256 hash but for sha256, there is. So need to write down the code ight?

3. Create signature using the above hash and the private key. ( Calculate the v,r,s components using crypto/ecdsa package.)
4. Create the signed transaction by appending these values to the transaction. I read somewhere that we can remove chainID from the signed transaction as its used in the calculation of v.
   type signedTransaction struct {
   Type                    uint8
   Nonce                   uint64
   BaseFeePerGas           uint64
   MaxPriorityFeePerGas    uint64
   MaxFeePerGas            uint64
   To                      string
   Value                   *big.Int
   Data                    string
   v                       *big.Int
   r                       *big.Int
   s                       *big.Int
   }

Could you confirm if the above declaration is right?

5. Serialize(RLP encode) the transaction and send it using the RPC method, eth_sendRawTransaction.

That gives me an error, as shown in the image.

What could be wrong here?

Thanks